# How does BMC know when Host initiates shutdown from its OS?

Tags: shutdown, bmc

I was reading about Intel Server Management and have this question. Through BMC web one can initiate a graceful shutdown to the Host OS, this is fine. But how does it work when OS initiates a poweroff/shutdown and BMC has to know it ?
Does BMC have to know from host cpu OS or does it monitor the CPU state somehow to know ?